# AFNetworking and its Repsonse (JSON). Simple check a value does not work?

Tags: ios, xcode, afnetworking

I have a problem with AFNetworking and its Response.
For you, this will be very simple to solve?! :-D

I receive a response as a json and then i use the values of the response.
The response in the log looks as follows:

```
{
    data = {
        name = john;
        newsletter = 1;
    };
    message = "Registered successfully";
    status = 200;
}
```

My code to use the name value looks like:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"username": mailTextField.text, @"password": passwordTextField.text, @"token": appToken, @"type": @"ios", @"action": @"register"};
[manager POST:appURLPUSH parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

        self.posts = (NSDictionary *)responseObject;
        self.post = self.posts[@"data"][@"name"];
        signNameLabel.text = (NSString *)self.post;
        signMailLabel.text = mailTextField.text;

        NSArray *menu = nil;

        if ((NSInteger)self.posts[@"data"][@"newsletter"] == 1) {
            NSLog(@"ITS ONE!");
            menu = @[@"newsletterunregister", @"signout"];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"MUST BE ZERO!");
            menu = @[@"newsletterregister", @"signout"];
        }

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        // Error handling
    }];
```

The thingy with the signNameLabel.text = (NSString *)self.post; works.
My problem is the line with if ((NSInteger)self.posts[@"data"][@"newsletter"] == 1) {. It never gets true. Why? I tried a few things like cast it to an NSString but it didn't work too.
So how i can check the item "newsletter" to be 1?

Thank you very much.
Titan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code

```
NSInteger newsletter = [self.posts[@"data"][@"newsletter"] IntegerValue];

            if (newsletter == 1) {
                NSLog(@"ITS ONE!");
                menu = @[@"newsletterunregister", @"signout"];
            } else {
                NSLog(@"MUST BE ZERO!");
                menu = @[@"newsletterregister", @"signout"];
            }
```